# sql - multi row insert for FK

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I have the following table:

```
| order_details | CREATE TABLE `order_details` (
  `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `client_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_id` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `serial` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `detail_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`detail_id`),
  KEY `order_id` (`order_id`),
  KEY `client_id` (`client_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `order_details_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`order_id`) REFERENCES `orders` (`order_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `order_details_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`client_id`) REFERENCES `clients` (`client_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=57 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

I am trying to insert values down multiple rows in the client_id column:

```
insert into order_details
    (`client_id`)
    values
    (1),
    (1),
    (1),
    (1),
    (2),
    (3),
    (14),
    (4),
    (5),
    (5),
    (5),
    (5),
    (7),
    ...
    (12),
    (13);
```

When I try to execute the insert with strict mode off, I receive a foreign key constraint failure (Err: 1452). However, it seems to be trying to insert into the order_id column as opposed to client_id (see err msg). What could be causing this error and how can I redirect the insert into the client_id column?

Error Msg:

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`db`.`order_details`, CONSTRAINT `order_details_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`order_id`) REFERENCES `orders` (`order_id`))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to list all non null columns in the insert:

```
insert into order_details
    (`client_id`, [other columns here])
values
(1, [other values here]),
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. If I already have values in those fields and do not want to override them should i just pass null?

Comment: @RayFoo How can you have values in those fields? These are new rows that you're creating.

Comment: The other option is to declare a `DEFAULT` value in the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Comment: Nvm I was mixing up insert and update, thanks for clearing things up for me

Answer (score 0):

Error statement is pretty straight forward ... you are trying to insert `null` value to `not null` columns like the below ones. Your `insert` statement is flawed.

```
   order_id int(11) NOT NULL
  `product_id` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `serial` int(11) NOT NULL,
```